# Search a inside a specific doc after getting its docId

Tags: java, lucene

Iam trying to implement a 2-stage search which first searches for a document title (stored as `StringField`) and after getting the `docId` of the matching document i want to search for a string **inside** that document's content(stored as `TextField`) and then highlight it using the usual Highlighter

EDIT
Rephrasing the question
*this is not the actual question.  Iam simply trying (my best) to avoid wrong/unhelpful answers*

Given the `docId` and the `Query` object search for the query specified in the `Query` object **inside** the document given by the `docId`

Comment: why don't you search inside document's content field direclty. later you can filter using docId

Comment: Can you help me in implementing that (if that will search only inside that document of course)

Comment: search in TextField first then you get doc ID's of all string matched documents. something like /select?q=TextField:"querystring"&fl=docID,TextField&hl=true&hl.fl=TextField   with that you get all string matched doc ID, TextField with keyword highlighted.

Comment: How do i implement this part `&fl=docID,TextField&hl=true&hl.fl=TextField`

Comment: Ok, i think i get what you are suggesting but thats not what iam looking for. I dont think you can query using the `docId`

Comment: Thats just solr URL. are you using Solr here or you are creating your own new search engine using  lucene index.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) in Solr to extract and index text of document. Document can be text file, PDF, PPT, XLS, DOC etc.

Comment: I believr this can be done without using all that stuff and Your answer doesn't answer my question

Comment: If u want to search inside document's content after getting `docId` of document, you have to index document's content before searching to get search results in real time. And before indexing you need to extract document's content, **Apache Tika** will do this job for you with very little efforts. It is not needed to use Solr, you can use **Tika** with **Lucene** library also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java to query your index try this one. source [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-lucene-to-index-and-search-text-files.html)

```
public static void searchIndex(String searchString) throws IOException, ParseException {
        System.out.println("Searching for '" + searchString + "'");
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.getDirectory(INDEX_DIRECTORY);
        IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(directory);
        IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(FIELD_CONTENTS, analyzer);
        Query query = queryParser.parse(searchString);
        Hits hits = indexSearcher.search(query);
        System.out.println("Number of hits: " + hits.length());

        Iterator<Hit> it = hits.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Hit hit = it.next();
            Document document = hit.getDocument();
            String path = document.get(FIELD_PATH);
            System.out.println("Hit: " + path);
        }

    }
```

Comment: 1. As I said in the comment, I dont think you can query for the `docId` 2. This is just a simple lucene search I know that and this does not answer my question. ... I'll try rephrasing my question

Comment: q=title:"searchquery"&fq=docID:2&hl=true.  this is like you search in title field and filter with docID and  highlight it

Comment: Help me with thay syntax please. More specifically what's `fq` and `hl` and `:2`.... I guess `hl` is highlight

Comment: yea correct hl is highlighting, fq is filter query, here fq=docID:2 means. filter the result documents with docID that has value 2.  are you using solr ?

Comment: No. But I think I'll need solr for this to work. Anyway to do this in lucene using java without solr?

Comment: yea I suggest you to use Solr. this way with lucene is little complex but doable.  if you are ready for it.  these links might help http://www.massapi.com/class/fi/FilteredQuery.html    and   https://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/FilteringOptions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110792/discussion-between-vinod-and-vulcan).